# c# charts with database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, charts

I am using charts and sql-server to preview data for gender (male & female). I don’t receive any error on the codes but the thing is that the chart is not showing anything whenever I debug.I don't know what I am missing here.

---

```
  private void chart()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=thokozani;Initial Catalog=payroll;Integrated Security=True");

        string sqlStr = "SELECT gender, COUNT(gender) from addnewemployee group by gender";

        SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myCommand.Fill(ds);

        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

        chart1.DataSource = source;

        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "gender";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "employeeid";
        chart1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: YValueMembers = "employeeid"; where is this in your data? Also: I usually bind a source to a series.

Comment: its in the same table(addnewemployee) as gender

Comment: but where is it in the select?

Comment: whenever put it on SELECT still it doesn't show anything

Comment: SELECT gender, COUNT(gender) from addnewemployee group by gender - This is the correct Select.

Comment: As it doesn't contain the yValueMember it is not correct. Show the corrected Select, please. Also __confirm that it returns the correct data__. - Other than that it should work.

Comment: Thanks for trying but i got the answer.

Comment: Good to hear. Since it won't serve any useful purpose, please delete the question!

Comment: Here is the example for what I was looking for : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-ASPNet-Chart-Control-from-Database-using-C-and-VBNet-Example.aspx